# Drag'n'Drop an draggable item through a form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop, draggable

I currently have two form:

- The first for my Favorite Menu
- The second for my Standard Menu.

Look like this :

```
<ui:define name="favoris">
        <h:form id="favForm">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function initDND() {
                    $(".draggable_item").draggable({ revert: true, helper: "clone" });
                }

                $(function(){
                    initDND();
                });
            </script>
            <p:remoteCommand name="activeDraggableFavoris" actionListener="favorisBean.menuModel" oncomplete="initDND()" />
            <p:tieredMenu model="#{favorisBean.menuModel}" id="panelMenu"
                style="width:198px" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

Standard Menu code look similar than Favoris Menu.
I want to drag my Item of my Standard Menu to my Favorite Menu to set it.

> Is this possible for a draggable Item to through over a form?

Comment: My copy/paste forgot to say "hi" sorry !

Comment: Just a little update. 
When you drag an item, the item can through the form. I can save my Favorite now but the item isn't renderer